# String slices in structs (in Rust)

Tags: string, struct, rust, lifetime

How do I tell Rust that I want a struct which contains a slice of a string?

I've tried:

```
struct Welcome {
    version: &str,
}
```

but the compiler complains:

```
src/chat.rs:16:14: 16:18 error: missing lifetime specifier [E0106]
src/chat.rs:16     version: &str,
```

From my limited understanding of Rust, I think a string slice is a pointer+length into some text allocated elsewhere.

I want the lifetime of the string slice to be the life time of the allocated text.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your understanding is mostly correct and you were just one step away from what you want. You can use a named lifetime in this way:

```
struct Welcome<'a> {
    version: &'a str,
}
```

This says that the &str reference must have the same lifetime as the containing Welcome struct.
More info on lifetimes can be found in [the lifetimes guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ownership.html#lifetimes)

Comment: Thanks for that answer.  The next (similar) thing I tried to do also failed with lifetime issues.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364310/references-in-structs-in-rust  I've googled the error, but not found anything helpful.